# properly closing adodb connections in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, adodb, mysql

in vb.net, there are some applications that use adodb to access a mysql server.

```
private adoconnect as new adodb.connection
public adors as new adodb.recordset

public function returnadors(byval column as string) as string
 return adors.fields(column).value.tostring
end function


Public Function ReadData(ByVal strQuery As String, Optional ByVal strWhere As String = vbNullString) As Boolean

        Try

            If ADOConnect.State = ConnectionState.Open Then Call CloseConnection()
            ADOConnect.Open(dsn, user, pass)
            ADORS.Open(strQuery, ADOConnect, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic)
            If not ADORS.EOF  Then Return True

        Catch ex As Exception

            msgbox(ex)

        End Try

        Return False

End Function

public sub closeconnection()
   if adoconnect.state = connectionstate.open then adoconnect.close
end sub
```

now lets say we wanted to populate a textbox with something from the database:

```
if readdata("SELECT NAME FROM USERS WHERE ID = 1") then
    me.textbox1.text = returnadors("NAME")
end if
call closeconnection
```

re writing these functions is a big task - and I am not interested in doing it unless absolutely needed.

**Here is my problem though.**

even if the connection is closed (and i have stepped through the code, it closes)
The connection is still visible on the sql server in a sleep state

why? and how can i make sure that the connection is closed.

thanks

Comment: It sounds too simple, but what if you change your code to close the adors prior to closing your connection?

Comment: do you mean closing the adoconnect in the readdata() function?

Comment: No, I mean [adors.Close](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ado/quickref/recordset_close.html) in the closeconnection function? EDIT - Also, set it to nothing after.

Comment: added it, still left the connection open in a sleep state on the server however

Comment: Apologies for the trial and error approach, but @Akram below is on the right path, the problem is (more than likely) connection pooling.  See [here](http://www.44342.com/ADO-f27-t3137-p1.htm) and [here](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-connection-pooling.html).

Comment: Thanks for the links - helped out. and i dont mind trial and error - thats the best way to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your `ConnectionString`:

```
Pooling=False;
```

Comment: Private cn As String = "DSN=dsn;uid=user;pwd=pw!;Pooling=false"     this still leaves the connection state as sleep on the server

Comment: Const cn As String = "DSN=dsn;uid=user;pwd=pw;OLE DB Services=-4"

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with exactly what you are doing, but this is usually the path I take with sqlserver connections. `Using` will automatically close your connection.

```
Using ADOconnect
   'operations
End Using
```

Comment: yeah but one problem i could think of with that would be once the readdata function is completed, and end using is reached the connection is closed. thus lets say if somewhere in form1 there use the returnadors function, the connection is closed and no data would be returned, just a error

Comment: Pretty sure it would re-open it.

Comment: let me try and see what happens, ill let you know

Comment: i get the error 'using' operand of type adodb.connection must implement 'system.idisposable'.